# Angular Material Expansion panel click event

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

```html
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false" (click)="getPrimaryAddress()">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      Primay Address
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{panelOpenState ? 'Hide' : 'Display'}} Address
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Street 1" [(ngModel)]="streetOneValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="streetOneValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="streetOneValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Street 2" [(ngModel)]="streetTwoValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="streetTwoValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="streetTwoValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Street 3" [(ngModel)]="streetThreeValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="streetThreeValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="streetThreeValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Street 2" [(ngModel)]="countyValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="countyValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="countyValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Post Code" [(ngModel)]="postcodeValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="postcodeValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="postcodeValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="primaryAddresscountryValue">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="primaryAddresscountryValue " matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="primaryAddresscountryValue=''">
                  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Just started playing around with Angular Material and have run into an issue with the mat-expansion-panel. My panel hosts a series of mat-form-field elements at appear when expanded.

I have several click events one that gets the data; (click)="getPrimaryAddress()
and the rest just clear the data once the X button is selected e.g (click)="streetOneValue=''"

However when I click the X button to clear a particular value the getPrimaryAddress() event fires again and just re-populates the data in the element. Is there anyway to stop the getPrimaryAddress() function from firing whenever I select the other click events?

I need the data to lazy load which is why I am handling it in a click event and not OnInit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the loading in the `opened` event you are already using. Then you don't need to use the click event and it is also more correct. From what I understand you want to load the data when the panel expands. There is also another `afterExpand` event you can also use.

You get the `click` event on the panel when you press a button because the buttons are child elements of the panel and you handle the `click` also in the panel element so both receive the event. Also any mouse click inside the panel will trigger another loading which I don't think is what you want. This is why it is better you use the specific events provided by the material components.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but perhaps it will help someone out there, who is looking for lazy loading (Lazy Rendering) via mat-expansion-panel.

"By default, the expansion panel content will be initialized even when the panel is closed. To instead defer initialization until the panel is open, the content should be provided as an ng-template:"

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       This is the expansion title
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        Some deferred content
    </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Source: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview